# Visual Studio: auto attach to a process when the process is spawned

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I want to attach to a process(a.exe) as soon as it is spawned, is it doable with VS? I only know the name of the process. Actually what I want to accomplish is set a breakpoint in c# code, but the code is belonging to another executable which will be launched by current running application(c.exe). The code is inside the initialize period so it is impossible for me to do the attach manually.

Comment: Can you give us more context? Do you own the process - is it your code?  Is that process calling out to your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I attach Visual Studio to a process that is not started yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167610/how-do-i-attach-visual-studio-to-a-process-that-is-not-started-yet)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

When I've faced this situation before (and I controlled both processes), I found a decent workaround is to put a call to [Debugger.Launch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) in the spawning process' entry point.  VS will then pop up a dialog box and let you attach to the process.

Comment: For me, I also had to add rights to my user to the local security policy: see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277353/6181641

Answer (score 37):

See the MSDN article, [How to: Launch the Debugger Automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.100).aspx) - this would allow one to skip the plethora of busywork clicking confirmation dialog boxes [without turning off UAC or other messing]. The article lists the following steps:

> 1. Start the Registry Editor (regedit).
> 2. In the Registry Editor, open the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` folder.
> 3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`.
> 4. In the **Image File Execution Options** folder, locate the name of the application you want to debug, such as *myapp.exe*. If you cannot
>    find the application you want to debug:
>    a. Right-click the **Image File Execution Options** folder, and on the shortcut menu, click **New Key**.
>    b. Right-click the new key, and on the shortcut menu, click **Rename**.
>    c. Edit the key name to the name of your application; *myapp.exe*, in this example.
> 5. Right-click the *myapp.exe* folder, and on the shortcut menu, click **New String Value**.
> 6. Right-click the new string value, and on the shortcut menu, click Rename.
> 7. Change the name to debugger.
> 8. Right-click the new string value, and on the shortcut menu, click **Modify**. The **Edit String** dialog box appears.
> 9. In the **Value data** box, type **vsjitdebugger.exe**.
> 10. Click **OK**.
> 11. From the **Registry** menu, click **Exit**.
> 12. The directory containing vsjitdebugger.exe must be in your system path. To add it to the system path, follow these steps:
>     a. Open the **Control Panel** in Classic view, and double-click **System**.
>     b. Click **Advanced System Settings**.
>     c. In **System Properties**, click the **Advanced** tab.
>     d. On the **Advanced** tab, click **Environment Variables**.
>     e. In the **Environment Variables** dialog box, under **System variables**, select **Path**, then click the **Edit** button.
>     f. In the **Edit System Variable** dialog box, add the directory to the **Variable value** box. Use a semicolon to separate it from
>     other entries in the list.
>     g. Click **OK** to close the **Edit System Variable** dialog box.
>     h. Click **OK** to close the **Environment Variables** dialog box.
>     i. Click **OK** to close the **System Properties** dialog box.
> 13. Now, use any method to start your application. Visual Studio will start and load the application

Comment: I like this answer because it works if your code is built in Release mode with PDBs on. The above Debugger.Launch() method does not work if built in Release mode.

Comment: I have needed to add also a string value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug called "Auto" with value 1 because without that vsjitdebugger fails on open

Comment: oh god why is this so involved

Comment: This is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

Another nice Solution is to use the Visual Studio Extension "ReAttach". Can be found [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8cccc206-b9de-42ef-8f5a-160ad0f017ae).

If your process is not currently running, ReAttach will ask you to start it and attach to it as soon as it becomes available.

Answer (score 11):

I have been looking for some way to do this when I launch a console application within an acceptance test.

I found this today - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool/

It's an add-on to visual studio, and it works a treat. When I debug an acceptance test (I use resharper test runner) and place a breakpoint within the app that gets launched, I can now debug the app in the same visual studio instance.

Comment: This is the easiest of all the solutions I've tried here.  Installs easily and just works.  No code changes required.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking! It allows to debug child process in the same VS instance. 
Quick note from docs: `The power tool requires a native debugger. This means if you are debugging .NET code, you must choose to enable mixed mode debugging`

Comment: top-notch solution

Answer (score 6):

["Entrian Attach"](http://entrian.com/attach/) is a Visual Studio add-in that does exactly this - you tell it the name of your executable and it attaches the debugger as the process starts, regardless of how it's started, before any code has run.

(Disclosure: I'm the author.  I built Attach because I have this problem all the time!)

Comment: Didn't work for me... I could see the symbols loading but then the process would continue running and quit.  Maybe it's because I was trying to attach to a process which I didn't have in the solution and therefore there was no breakpoint.

Comment: @NelsonRothermel: I'd like to help, but Stack Overflow isn't the place for Entrian Solutions tech support.  :-)  Email me (richie@entrian.com) if you'd like me to try to help with your problem - there are some easy things to try.

Comment: I ended up getting it working with gflags.exe and the key for me was to break on a certain exception type, so I think your solution would have actually worked if I would have set it up correctly.  I won't be needing it now, but it's an interesting add-in I may have a use for in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use gflags.exe util that comes with Windows Debugging tools, all you need to do is open gflags.exe then go to image file enter the process name (a.exe) press tab and check the debugger checkbox, in the TextBox enter the vs path with the option /debugexe (i.e. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /debugexe)

The automatically visual studio will open once the process is running you can add your breakpoints and press Run.

Answer (score 2):

How about this: open project for `a.exe` in VS, set the breakpoints etc. Then open *Project Properties* for a.exe, *Debugging* tab, and set *Command* to `c.exe`. Then just hit *Debug*.

Unfortunately I never did this with managed projects, so I can be off the mark here. However, that's how I would do it with unmanaged (C++) projects. I think managed debugger should support it too.

Comment: In my situation, the executable I want to debug is launched as part of the start-up of another executable. I would guess that's the driving force behind the question.

Comment: Worked for me. Quick and easy for direct cases but possibly not good for more complex ones.

Answer (score -1):

If C# code being launched by unmanaged code then make sure you check "Unmanaged code debugging" @Project properties --> debug options..

Answer (score -1):

I really liked [Entrian Attach](http://entrian.com/attach/) as suggested by @RichieHindle, but I also found this free tool that does something similar. It catches all processes started by the debugging process.

Spawned Process Catcher:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Brubtsov.SpawnedProcessCatcher

Comment: This module wouldn't install on VS 2013, 2015, or 2017.  Hasn't been updated since late 2013.

Answer (score -1):

As of VS 2013 SP2, there's a free tool from Microsoft, which does the same as "Spawned Process Catcher" mentioned before - attaching all processes, which are started by a process already in debugging. Note: I have only tested this with unmanaged C++ (this works flawlessly).

[Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GreggMiskelly.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool#overview)

[MSDN Blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool/)