# Debug 2+ instances of same project with different config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I'm writing a distributed app and testing requires that I run more than one instance at a time.

Is it possible to debug two or more distinct instances of the same project (at the simplest, passing in different command-line options)?

Comment: Can't you just attach the debugger to multiple instances? Debug -> Attach

Comment: Yes, but that's pretty cumbersome. Was wondering if there's an slicker way.

Comment: @spender How slick do you need it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, attach to both processes (Debug -> Attach to Process).  They will appear under the Processes debug window and their threads will be grouped/headed by process in the Threads window.

Comment: Any way to make this less cumbersome? That's quite some number of clicks.

Comment: You could bind a shortcut key to Attach to Process, or put a `Debugger.Launch` call at the start of the process, it will prompt you to attach

Comment: See also Manuel's answer here, you may be able to write a macro like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030071/visual-studio-2010-automatic-attach-to-process

Comment: Now we're talking. `Debugger.Launch` looks good. Didn't know about that. Thanks.

Comment: I think I'll add a compilation symbol in a new project configuration and call `Debugger.Launch` wrapped in `#if`/`#endif`. That will work nicely for me. Thanks again.

Comment: Good tip :) didn't know about this myself